# symfony2 twig FileException: Unable to create the "/voice_mails" directory

Tags: symfony, permissions

```
$r = $app['request'];
foreach ($r->files as $uploadedFile) {
      $name = basename($_FILES["wavFile"]["name"]);
      $file = $uploadedFile->move('/voice_mails', $name);
      print_r($file);
}
```

> I am trying to upload file using above code , But throwing error like:
>   **FileException: Unable to create the "/voice_mails" directory**
>   Please Help me.

Comment: Check permissions and path!

Comment: Path where create /voice_mailes must be writable for apache

Comment: @Cuchu. Thanks for reply.  permission is 0777, where it will try to create folder **voice_mails** ????

Comment: /voice_mails - is incorrect path. It's means search this folder from root of fs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console

```
mkdir your_path/voice_mails
chmod -R 777 your_path/voice_mails
chown -Rf apache:apache your_path/voice_mails
```

And check fisical path /var/www/yourproject or use dirname()

Comment: Thanks. if use /home/XXX/public_html/training/app/web/voice_mails.  It WORKS ..!

Answer (score 1):

FileException is thrown because you're trying to create `voice_mails` directory in root folder `/`. You want to create in in your **web root** folder, so you code should be like:

```
foreach ($r->files as $uploadedFile) {
    //…
    $file = $uploadedFile->move($this->get('kernel')->getRootDir() . '/../web/voice_mails', $name);
    //…
}
```